# How to restore weights of Inception V3 and retrain only the last layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have followed this tutorial (https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/#1) successfully. I have trained on my own data and that works. However now I want to continue training on the last layer that I have spent a day training. However when I simply rerun the command

```
python -m scripts.retrain \
  --bottleneck_dir=tf_files/bottlenecks \
  --how_many_training_steps=500 \
  --model_dir=tf_files/models/ \
  --summaries_dir=tf_files/training_summaries/"${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --output_graph=tf_files/retrained_graph.pb \
  --output_labels=tf_files/retrained_labels.txt \
  --architecture="${ARCHITECTURE}" \
  --image_dir=tf_files/flower_photos
```

the training starts back at 0.

I want to do this, because I wish to adjust the learning rate as learning continues (and potentially other values aswell)

In particular the retrain.py file (https://github.com/googlecodelabs/tensorflow-for-poets-2/tree/master/scripts) is interesting. I also tried to copy the some code from label_image.py into retrain.py, but with no success.

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea, as the whole network's weights are updated depending on the previous layers

Comment: if I understod correctly, then only the final layers weights are being adjusted in the retraining. In particular the whole bottleneck system would make no sense if all weights are adjusted.

Comment: oh sorry, I get it now. So, I think you should load the whole network weights and only unfreeze the final layer. Then you retrain.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49885353/5330223