# Regarding number of non-trainable layers in transfer learning

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I am experimenting VGG16 and InceptionV3 model for my dataset.

One kernel I saw in Kaggle which uses InceptionV3 model had set the 51 initial layers as non-trainable.

On the other hand, somewhere I saw a VGG16 model was used and except last 4 layers all were set as non-trainable.

I am looking for a common generalized approach about how many layers should I set as non-trainable for any model.

Or any basic checklist-list sort of things from which I could decide for my problem statement.

I saw this [Transfer learning from the pre-trained NASnet network. How to know the number of layers to freeze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572918/transfer-learning-from-the-pre-trained-nasnet-network-how-to-know-the-number-of) but could not understand the answer as why that particular point was selected